# How to make web page fill iPhone browser?

Tags: asp.net, browser, mobile

I'm writing an ASP.NET web site targeted at cellphones.

The pages appear fine on a Nokia browser, but on the iPhone, the text is all squashed up into the top left hand corner of the page.

Is there some way of making the mobile browser automatically zoom in to fit the text on the page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to have a look at this:

[User Experience Coding How-To's for Safari on iPhone](http://developer.apple.com/safari/library/codinghowtos/Mobile/UserExperience/index.html)

It provides information on user scaling / zooming as well as conditionally loading CSS for iPhone/iPod specific devices.

Answer (score 1):

Put this inside your head:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```